# Trigger an alert at specific time with VBA on Excel

Tags: vba, excel

I have a code that copies that every time I received an email the time received is copied on Excel and I need to trigger a message when it has been 1:50hr from the received time of certain emails. For example:

```
Received Time       Deadline
13/09/2018 9:44     13/09/2018 11:34   (run code at 11:34)
13/09/2018 10:27    13/09/2018 12:17   (run code at 12:17)
```

(received times are in column B and deadlines in column C)

I know there is the appication.ontime method which is what I've been trying to use but didn't succed. This is what I've got so far:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    For Each cell In Sheets("sheet").Range(Range("C2"), Range("C2").End(xlDown))
            Application.OnTime TimeValue(cell.Value), "deadline_alert"
    Next cell
End Sub

Public Sub deadline_alert()

MsgBox "check email"

End Sub
```

Also I need this code to be active all the time. I won't be using this Excel, it's just there to get the information from Outlook. Should I do this on the workbook event Open or WorksheetDeactivate?

Comment: Have you tried outlook-vba? Seems like a better fit here

Comment: I did! But i can't set reminders, actually I can, but it's a shared mailbox so I don't even know who gets them.. I also tried to set a rule to copy these mails to my mailbox and then set them.. but it's the same, I can't  neither set rules to that inbox folder nor reminders..

Comment: I found out that the problem has nothing to do with the coding but something else. Should I post the new problem in the answer or start a new question?

Comment: New question is best if it's significantly different. If it's not about programming it may not be applicable to SO though.